# Flink - serializable of class (not POJO)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is it not possible to serialize classes which are not POJO in apache flink?
I have an utility class which has many functions and i want to send the Source function an object of that utility class, but flink is throwing serialization exception.

Main Class:

```
Utilities utilities = new Utilities();
DataStream<MyData> dataStream = env.addSource(new MySource(configData,utilities))
```

Utilities class :

```
public class Utilities {


    public Utilities() {
        //default constructor
    }


    public String fun1() {

        //Do something  
    }   

    public String fun2() {

        //Do something  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Utilities` implement `Serializable`.